# ionic can't send the data

Tags: angularjs, tcp, ionic-framework

I have created my service and controller but, still I can't get and send any data.I don't know where is the problem. Any help will be appreciated.
Here is the code:

**Factory**

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['btford.socket-io'])
.factory('mySocket', function(socketFactory){
  var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://192.168.2.5:3000');
  mySocket = socketFactory({
    ioSocket: myIoSocket
  });

  return mySocket;
})
```

**Contoller**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['btford.socket-io'])
.controller('DashCtrl',function($scope,mySocket) {
  $scope.gonder = function(){
    mySocket.on('news', function (data) {
      console.log('a');
      console.log(data);
      mySocket.emit('my other event', { my: data });
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: Are those "factory" and "controller;" pieces of text not related to your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

**Factory:**

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['btford.socket-io'])
.factory('mySocket', function(){
  return {
    getAllData: function() {
      return $http.get('http://192.168.2.5:3000');
    }
  }
})
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['btford.socket-io'])
.controller('DashCtrl',function($scope,mySocket) {
  mySocket.getAllData().then(function(result){
    console.log('a');
    console.log(result);
  });
})
```

Hope it will help you.